# WebBrowser font size in pixels

Tags: c#, html, fonts, browser, size

I am trying to set the font size in C# WebBrowswer in pixels.

I tried:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Write(@"<span style=""font-size:10px"">TEXT </span>");
```

but the number before "px" doesn't seem to have any affect.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Whole function:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    webBrowser1.Document.Write("<span style=\"font-size: 50px; color: #f00; \">Big Red Writing!</span>");
}
```

**Update:**
I tested the exe file on another pc and it worked properly. But here, even `<font size="7">...</font>` doesn't work. All give the same size.
Any ideas?

Comment: You're forgetting `;`

Comment: have you tried my answer below

Comment: @Arshad: It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about resetting the Internet explorer settings using this fix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737
and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try terminated quotes (`\"`) without using string literal. I have tried this and works 100%:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Write("<span style=\"font-size: 50px; color: #f00;\">Big Red Writing!</span>");
```

Comment: No. It's a string literal.

Comment: @Jerry - Try my snippet (I've removed the string literal @). I've tried this and it works, showing large red writing.

Comment: I tired it. It's red, but still the number doesn't affect the font size.

Comment: Suggests something strange is happening then because it is obviously parsing the style element because you can see the colour change! Are you sure you are copying exactly as it is and no characters are getting lost? Have you got something else overriding the element? Is anything else being rendered in the document that might cause this?

Comment: I added the whole Load function in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
HtmlDocument objHtmlDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
objHtmlDoc.Write("<span style=\"font-size:10px\">TEXT </span>");
```

Comment: are you getting any error... i have tested it, by writing in form_load event. its working

Comment: No, it displays the text, but the number has no effect on the text size. Try changing it.

Comment: you can check it out, its working, check `font-size:40px` and see

Comment: Just tested. No effect on size.

Comment: @Jerry, can you share your load function ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the first post. Also please check the update.

Comment: @Jerry, I have tested your code as well as mine, both are working fine,

Comment: You can try it again by creating new application and do not change any property for webbrowser control, just add it to the form and write code in the form_load event

Comment: I did that. Still no change